# Menu items not shown in menu bar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have the same problem as posted many times [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818294/android-studio-menu-not-showing-in-app) or [here](https://www.androidpit.com/forum/598727/please-help-i-can-not-get-icons-to-appear-in-action-bar). I define a menu item which shows up in the preview in `AndroidStudio`:

[image]

But when I run the app on my phone the icon (a `png` image) is not visible, and there is a lot of space available. However, this 'Add' option shows up in the Options menu (to the very right; together with 'Srttings'). Here is my `menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_favourite"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add"
        android:title="@string/menu_add"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

I tried the suggestions I could find, but none of them solved my problem. My phone is a LG G3. How can I solve this problem?

Additional information: `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could your share your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` code?

Comment: Please see updated question; I have no method `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`...

Comment: Have you tried moving your `onCreateOptionsMenu` to the `onPrepareOptionsMenu`? The documentation says that `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. My bet is that inflating the menu on `onCreateOptionsMenu` the system has not yet computed the menu's size and all your menu options are shown in overflow.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you suggest. I replaced the method name `onCreateOptionsMenu` with `onPrepareOptionsMenu` which does not solve my problem, and things even get worse. I am not sure what you mean by 'moving' one method to the other method...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `app:showAsAction="always"` and `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` then it will show.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_favourite"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add"
        android:title="@string/menu_add"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

You're probably using the support library which is dependent on the app namespace. If in doubt, just add the same property twice (`android:` and `app:` namespaces).

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but still I do not see the name `Add` in the menu bar. Exact same behavior as before...

Comment: If you use the supplied code, there should be the icon in the toolbar and settings option in the overflow menu. What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: Just as in the posted image in the menu bar, but just without the 'plus' icon in the menu bar. It says 'Testapp' on the left, and I see the three dots at the right. When I tap on those three dots, I see the 'Add' menu (and a 'Settings menu').

Comment: I just updated the sample with the full source and it's working as expected on my GT-I9100. Please make sure you recompile your project, since minor xml changes might not get detected.

Comment: This solution works on my Nexus 4. The critical part is that `android:showAsAction="always"` should be `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Yes, finally!! Man, android is really a pain in the a... One very tiny, tiny step takes you hours! But thanks anyway..

Comment: Been there ;) Had the same issue multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate()` add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`

And you are probably inflating the wrong menu file.